# How to return new array with .map synchronic?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make something synchronic in node.js and I face some problems with this.
How can I get the array `newArr` that each item will be the return object from `then`?

```
Rating.find({userID: req.body.id}).then( (ratings) => {

   var newArr = ratings.map( (rating) => {

        User.find({_id: rating.reviewerID}).then( (user) => {        
               return {
                 firstName: user[0].firstName,
                 text: rating.text,
                 rating: rating.rating
               }
        }) 
    })

    console.log(newArr);

});
```

Comment: You cant change the asynchronous nature of things

Comment: so I need to put the User.find outside the .map() to make it work?

Comment: No, put a `return` in front of User.find, them wrap the map call into `Promise.all`, then newArr is a Promise that resolves to the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

**your way is not correct**

```
Rating.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        localField: "reviewerID",
        from: "user",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "some_data"
    },
},

], function(err, data) {
     if (err) throw err
     if (!data)return res.send('data not ');
     return res.status(200).json(data)
   }
})
```

[**You can also check this link**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/**)